# Extract all ip addresses with sed and awk from a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

It is simple to extract all ip addresses with grep from a string.

```
string="221.11.165.237xxxx221.11.165.233\n
219.158.9.97ttttt219.158.19.137"
echo $string |grep -oP "(\d+\.){3}\d+"
221.11.165.237
221.11.165.233
219.158.9.97
219.158.19.137
```

The regrex pattern is simple  `(\d+\.){3}\d+`.
Do the same job with sed and awk.
For sed:

```
echo $string | sed 's/^\(\(\d\+\.\)\{3\}\d\+\)$/\1/g'
221.11.165.237xxxx221.11.165.233\n 219.158.9.97ttttt219.158.19.137
```

For awk:

```
echo $string |gawk 'match($0,/(\d+\.){3}\d+/,k){print k}'
echo $string |awk '/(\d+\.){3}\d+/{print}'
```

How to fix it for sed and gawk(awk)?
The expect output is the same as grep.

```
221.11.165.237
221.11.165.233
219.158.9.97
219.158.19.137
```

Comment: What is the expected output, please post it too.

Comment: see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) and [cross site duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279368/sed-regular-expression-behaving-differently-than-in-vim-and-perl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/!s/[0-9.]\+/\n&\n/;/^\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\n/P;D' file
```

Insert newlines either side of strings consisting only of numbers and periods. If a line contains only an IP address print it.

An easier-on-the-eye rendition uses the `-r` option:

```
sed -r '/\n/!s/[0-9.]+/\n&\n/;/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\n/P;D' <<<"$string"
```

Answer (score 3):

Very few tools will recognize `\d` as meaning `digits`. Just use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead:

```
$ echo "$string" | awk -v RS='([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+' 'RT{print RT}'
221.11.165.237
221.11.165.233
219.158.9.97
219.158.19.137
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT. With any awk:

```
$ echo "$string" | awk '{while ( match($0,/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/) ) { print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) } }'
221.11.165.237
221.11.165.233
219.158.9.97
219.158.19.137
```

Comment: and the regrex for sed?

Comment: It's simply not a job for sed. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. When you try to do anything more than that with sed you get into jumbled piles of single-character runes and non-portable constructs. If you're doing something more than `s/old/new/` just use awk. Not saying you CAN'T force some specific version of sed to do what you want but the result involves language constructs that literally became obsolete in the mid 1980s when awk was invented.

Comment: Get no output with mawk or original-awk ?

Comment: man mawk : AWK  uses  extended  regular expressions as with egrep(1).  The regular expression metacharacters, i.e., those with special meaning in  regular expressions are ^ $ . [ ] | ( ) * + ? so we must replace {3} by +

Comment: @ctac_ `egrep` has been deprecated in favor of `grep -E` for many years. Original-awk is also known as old, broken awk and must never be used by anyone for any purpose so in any discussion about what does/doesn't work in awk don't even consider that since almost nothing works in it. mawk has several versions, some very old, pre-POSIX and with limited features since it was focused on speed of execution over functionality. Interval Expressions like `{3}` are part of EREs (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and are supported by all current versions of all awks including mawk.

Answer (score 0):

As you weren't specific about what could be between the ip addresses, I went with the fact that only numbers and periods will be in the ip:

```
echo "$string" | sed -r 's/[^0-9.]+/\n/'

echo "$string" | awk '1' RS="[^0-9.]+"
```

Comment: Could you explain `awk '1' RS="[^0-9.]+"` in detail ?

Comment: That will only work in GNU awk and will find many false matches, not just IP addresses.

Comment: Essentially the awk and sed are the same in that they replace any consecutive non-digit or period with a new line.  The 1 is simply to print out the new format.  Ed is correct, but as per my assumption stated it was only designed to work in a special case