# How do I extract all the ip addresses from the string using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string from which I would like to extract all the ip addresses. I'm very new to bash. Please help

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IP=$(ping -c 25 x.x.x.255)
```

"$IP" will have the following text. Please suggest a way to get only the ip addresses like x.x.x.252, x.x.x.141 ......

```
PING x.x.x.255 (x.x.x.255): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from x.x.x.252: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
64 bytes from x.x.x.141: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=2.200 ms
64 bytes from x.x.x.197: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=70.087 ms
64 bytes from x.x.x.108: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=70.136 ms

--- x.x.x.255 ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 packets received, +12 duplicates, 0.0% packet loss
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract all ip addresses with sed and awk from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604723/extract-all-ip-addresses-with-sed-and-awk-from-a-string)

Comment: what code have you tried? what results are generated by your code? what are the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep's -E and -o options:

```sh
$ ips=$(ping -c 4 example.com | grep -Eo '\s([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+\s')
$ echo $ips
93.184.216.34 93.184.216.34 93.184.216.34 93.184.216.34
```

The regex matches a space `\s`, followed by a capturing group consisting of one or more digits `[0-9]+` and a dot `\.` repeated three times `{3}`, followed by `[0-9]+\s`. Information about grep's options can be found in  [`man grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).